# Open-ended Bernoulli distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

I've found myself puzzled by the following simple discrete distribution: **open-ended Bernoulli distribution**, which I will now define.

The distribution has 2 parameters: $p$, the success probability, and $q$, the repeat probability. I will define it recursively as follows:
\begin{equation}
X = \begin{cases}
0 & (1-p)(1-q)\\
1 & p(1-q)\\
X' & (1-p)q\\
1+X' & pq
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where the right column of the "cases" environment represents probabilities (it sums to 1) and the left column represents the "result" of $X$, where $X'$ is an independent random variable sharing the same distribution as $X$ (with the same parameters).

Of course, $X$ can be infinite, but this happens with probability 0 (at least when $q<1$); also, it seems that the mean will always be finite (again, when $q<1$). However, I am not only interested in the mean, but rather in the full **pmf**; I am interested in its shape, in the moments, etc.

## Some effort

Here's some effort I've made: I tried to understand some edge particular cases. Here it is:

### The case $p=0$

This is easy, as in this case $X\equiv 0$.

### The case $p=1$

In this case this is a geometric distribution (the version whose support does not include 0).

### The case $q=0$

In this case $X$ is a Bernoulli trial.

### The case $q=1$

In this case, unless $p=0$, $X$ is always $\infty$.

## More generality

In fact, in a more general and more interesting case, the parameters $a,b,a^+,b^+$ replace $p,q$ as follows:
\begin{equation}
X = \begin{cases}
0 & a\\
1 & b\\
X' & a^+\\
1+X' & b^+
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Can you find the **pmf**?

Comment: Is there a reason for using the 'peculiar' notations $a^+$ and $b^+$?

Comment: not really... + signifies contonuation, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $a^+$ and $b^+$ I use $c$ and $d$ respectively. Note that $a+b+c+d=1$.

$P\left\{ X=0\right\} =a+cP\left\{ X=0\right\} $ so: $$P\left\{ X=0\right\} =\frac{a}{1-c}$$

$P\left\{ X=1\right\} =b+cP\left\{ X=1\right\} +dP\left\{ X=0\right\} $
so: $$P\left\{ X=1\right\} =\frac{b}{1-c}+\frac{ad}{\left(1-c\right)^{2}}$$

If $n>0$ then $P\left\{ X=n+1\right\} =cP\left\{ X=n+1\right\} +dP\left\{ X=n\right\} $
so: $$P\left\{ X=n+1\right\} =\frac{d}{1-c}P\left\{ X=n\right\} $$

This makes it possible to prove by induction that:

$$P\left\{ X=n\right\} =\frac{bd^{n-1}}{\left(1-c\right)^{n}}+\frac{ad^{n}}{\left(1-c\right)^{n+1}}$$
for $n\geq1$ and under condition $a+b>0$.